# Value is correct when logged in Console but is undefined when using in variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios, react-context

I fetched data from an API which gave me an object. When I tried to console log a specific value from the data i worked fine but when i tried using it as a variable i'm getting an error:

> Cannot Read property from '.....' of undefined.

I'm using ReactJS.

This Is the Code Where I'm trying to access the value

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from "react";
import ApexContext from "../context/apexContext";

const Overview = () => {
  const apexContext = useContext(ApexContext);


  const { gamer } = apexContext;

  const test = () => {
    console.log(gamer.platformInfo.platformSlug);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <img
          src="https://trackercdn.com/cdn/apex.tracker.gg/ranks/gold4.png"
          alt="Rank"
        />
        <h2>Active Legend: {gamer.platformInfo.platformSlug}</h2>
      </div>
      <div className="ui raised very padded text container segment">
        <button className="ui button" onClick={test}>
          Test
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Overview;
```

I am Using Context BTW.
Here IS the Code in which gamer object is being stored as an object

```
import React, { useReducer } from "react";
import Axios from "axios";
import ApexContext from "./apexContext";
import ApexReducer from "./apexReducer";
import {
  METADATA,
  PLATFORM_INFO,
  STATS,
  LOADING_TRUE,
  LOADING_FALSE,
  GAMER,
} from "./types";

const ApexState = (props) => {
  const InitialState = {
    metadata: {},
    platformInfo: {},
    overallStats: {},
    loading: false,
    gamer: {},
  };

  // Iniialize Reducer
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(ApexReducer, InitialState);

  // Finding The Specific Gamer Details
  const getGamer = async (platform, gamerId) => {
    dispatch({
      type: LOADING_TRUE,
    });

    const res = await Axios.get(
      `http://localhost:5000/api/v2/profile/${platform}/${gamerId}`
    );

    dispatch({
      type: GAMER,
      payload: res.data.data,
    });

    dispatch({
      type: LOADING_FALSE,
    });
  };

  return (
    <ApexContext.Provider
      value={{
        // loading: state.loading,
        // activeLegend: state.metadata.activeLegendName,
        // platformInfo: state.platformInfo,
        // overallStats: state.overallStats,
        gamer: state.gamer,
        getGamer,
      }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </ApexContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default ApexState;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try conditional rendering

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from "react";
import ApexContext from "../context/apexContext";

const Overview = () => {
  const apexContext = useContext(ApexContext);

  const { gamer } = apexContext;

  const test = () => {
    console.log(gamer.platformInfo.platformSlug);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <img
          src="https://trackercdn.com/cdn/apex.tracker.gg/ranks/gold4.png"
          alt="Rank"
        />
        <h2>
          Active Legend:
          { gamer?.platformInfo?.platformSlug
            ? gamer.platformInfo.platformSlug
            : null}
        </h2>
      </div>
      <div className="ui raised very padded text container segment">
        <button className="ui button" onClick={test}>
          Test
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Overview;
```

// Update on this answer

You can achieve the same using optional chaining
{ gamer?.platformInfo?.platformSlug}

Looks elegant, isn't it?

Comment: Thanks Man. You Saved me a ton of time. this works flawlessly

Comment: Accept and upvote the answer if that works for you thanks ✌

Answer (score 0):

The reason of that issue is your `gamer` object is arriving asynchronously from the API. Once you run the `test` function with `onClick` trigger the data already arrived.

Try checking for `null` values as:

```
<h2>Active Legend: { gamer && gamer.platformInfo.platformSlug }</h2>
```

In this way, it will try to access `platformInfo` property once `gamer` has a different value from `null` or `undefined`.